# bug in Ionic 4 back button restart app (DOM) when you are in root Cordova/App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

When user clicks over hardware back button of Android app built with Ionic 4. It just restart the without executing subscribed code.

```js
self.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  /// login/product
  if (window.location.pathname === '/login/product') {
    self.appMinimize.minimize();
  }
});
```

Any changes made from Ionic 4 team that causes this issue - before 3-4 days it was working fine.

Please any one tell us when it could be fixed - what needs to be updated to fix this issue.?